# How to recover lost items on Menu strip and Toolbar strip

Tags: c#, winforms, toolbar, menubar

I have this problem that i have many buttons and labels on my `Strips` with many codes but suddenly it disappear and i don't know why. i didn't do anything except deleting pictures on resources but after deleting of-course there are errors and i resolve it. i always do that when ever there are excess pictures that i imported so that it lessen the mess. that's why i don't have any idea why this happen. i already search on Google but then there are no topic related to my problem. please any help suggestion is very appreciate

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question. Compare your code before and after, see waht you did wrong.

Comment: `git diff HEAD~`? You're using version control, right?

Comment: I guess this may be stuck forever :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its important that you stop and take a copy of your project folder before you proceed. After you have a copy do not open your solution. whats happened is that your resources.resx is likely corrupted and you may have attempted to fix it in a way that can do permanent damage to your project.

After you have taken a copy of your project folder open the form.cs files in your back up folder with notepad, not in the ide, and determine whether or not you have your code. your resources can be repaired separately.

In order to repair your resources, after you have backed up your code, you will need to identify the exact error that it complains about when you try to open the designer. Make sure you don't do these repairs on the backup copy of your project.

If your issue is missing resources (or so it says) you can rclick your project in the solution explorer and delete them one at a time, in particular if they show errors, you can also try to highlight the resources.resx file and rclick, run custom tool to regenerate it.

The last place to look is in the properties of your project, go through each of the categories, make sure they are ok, if they display errors, delete them from there. Close vs and restart it before you try the designer again.

Im describing this as I know it for VS 2012, be very careful though, All you have is that backup folder to try again from.